# Render completely messed up?

Tags: rendering

I have a problem when rendering my scene. It looks like after a certain distance everything is blurred out completely, some objects are missing and some other weird things are going on. However in the viewport the rendered view is fine. Camera clipping is set to 0.1-100 m so it shouldn't be a problem. Do you have any idea what is going on?
[image]

[image]

Edit: Here's the link to the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y-KGw-IL2_nANx8E8zrJw_N8B_fsM7RB

Comment: Does this happen while rendering on the CPU or GPU?

Comment: It happens in both cases.

Comment: Can you share the .blend file with us? My bet would've been either a clipping issue or artefacts due to buggy GPU driver.

Comment: The denoiser would be another suspect.

Comment: I added the .blend file to the description. Turning off the denoiser doesn't seem to help :/

Comment: The problem first appeared when I added the particle system, so I made a render without them but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a (large scale) copy of the axe head in your scene that is hidden in the viewport but not in the render. Activate the restrictions toggles by clicking on the filter icon in the outliner, most importantly the *Disable in Renders* toggle (camera icon).

Toggled the viewport visibility (eye icon) to show the hidden axe head
[image: Show axes head]

*Hide in Viewport*, *Disable in Viewports* and *Disable in Renders* can be used to hide it an object both in viewports and renders.

[image: Hidden in viewports and render]

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much for checking.