# Avoid rendering hidden objects (blender 2.8)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Is there a way to stop blender from rendering hidden objects (that do not show in the rendered view)?

Comment: Hello :). I'm sure you're familiar with the *Enable/Disable in Render* switch (camera icon). So are you looking for a script that will also disable all hidden object from render?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render completely messed up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150531/render-completely-messed-up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *Outliner* you can toggle visibility and renderability of objects.

Click on the funnel icon on the top right and enable different filters.

The **Eye** icon determines visibility in the 3d viewport.

The **Monitor** icon disables the object in all viewports.

The **Camera** icon determines if the object is rendered or not.

[image]

Read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner/interface.html

---

### Alternatively

The visibility of an object can also be set in the ***Visibility*** controls Object Properties.

[image]

Comment: Just to add - the checkmark disables collections from both viewport + render at once.

Comment: And the arrow makes the object selectable or not