# Something covers my character in render

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have render this image but don't know something cover my character in render. Please help[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you have a hidden object? Objects hidden in the viewport are still visible in renders.

Comment: Can I sent you the blend file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid rendering hidden objects (blender 2.8)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185347/avoid-rendering-hidden-objects-blender-2-8)

Comment: Yeah, you can upload it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have added blend, please help

Comment: I downloaded the file. The problem doesn't occur on my end. The only thing I would call an "abnormality" is a box around the eyes named "EyeBoolean" that doesn't seem to appear as intended in the render.

Comment: I do the viewport render animation

Comment: Try it, did it  occur

Comment: That's strange; I downloaded the file, and I don't have that problem at all (and yes, I'm looking at the viewport render).  It may just be glitch.  Have you tried closing and reopening Blender, or even just restarting your device?  That has tended to resolve any glitches I encounter.

Comment: No it don't work