# Purple bits appear when I render using blender render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to make a doughnut from a tutorial but apparently there's some extra purple bits on the bottom of the donut when using Blender Render:
[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

the donut have a subsurface rad of 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 and the color of bread with subsurface color of lighter bread, the icing have a subsurface rad of 0.3, 0,1, 0.1 and pink color and subsurf is pinkish-red color. the plane has a color of pink.

my version is 2.81

and here is my collection

[image]

Comment: @susu the donut have a subsurface rad of 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 and the color of bread with subsurface color of lighter bread, the icing have a subsurface rad of 0.3, 0,1, 0.1 and pink color and subsurf is pinkish-red color. the plane has a color of pink.

Comment: Have you made a backup/archive? There might be 2 donuts rendered overlapping

Comment: @Blunder Yes, but I turned off the visibility for the archive.

Comment: Yes, please add a screenshot of the blender window and the blender version that you use. To me it looks loke you have 2 donuts and 2 icings rendered. The "eye" icon is just for viewport visibility.

Comment: @Blunder then how do I do it for blender render visibility? also my version is 2.81

Comment: Read [Avoid rendering hidden objects in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185347/avoid-rendering-hidden-objects-blender-2-8/185356#185356)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a backup copy of your donut and icing are still rendered. The image displays 2 versions of the donut+icing.

**To fix this in Blender 2.8x:** Like mentioned by susu in the comment, you need to display the "camera" icon in the filter settings first. Then you can enable/disable the rendering of objects or whole collections in the outline: [Avoid rendering hidden objects (blender 2.8)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185347/avoid-rendering-hidden-objects-blender-2-8/185356#185356)

In **Blender 2.9x** the collections have a checkbox. If you uncheck it, then it automatically disables visibility in viewport and rendering.

[image]