# Fail in render only half image

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

Hi when I went to render the image, something fail- I think maybe is the focal lenght? Or the distance of rendering? Thanks
thanks
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have another floor, which is hidden in the viewport, but still renders. It would be easier to help if you linked your .blend file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It looks like there is a plane that is likely hidden for the viewport but enabled for rendering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid rendering hidden objects (blender 2.8)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185347/avoid-rendering-hidden-objects-blender-2-8)